# Javascript image not changing

Tags: javascript, onclick

The image is not changing to another image on the onclick event, until the page is minimized/maximized the url to this is here: http://craft.yuribot.ml/

javascript here:

```
function CallPlay(plybtn, pbtn) {
    if (pbtn.style.display == "block") {
        pbtn.style.display = 'none';
        plybtn.style.display = "block";
        console.log('CallPlay');
    }
}

function CallPause(plybtn, pbtn) {
    if (plybtn.style.display == 'block') {
        plybtn.style.display = 'none';
        pbtn.style.display = "block";
        console.log('CallPause');
    }
}

var isPlaying = false;
var player = document.createElement('div');
var title = document.createElement('p');
var plybtn = document.createElement('img');
var pbtn = document.createElement('img');
pbtn.style.display = "none";
plybtn.style.display = 'block';
player.style.height = '19px';
player.style.width = '100%';
player.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://craft.yuribot.ml/Player/src/Images/base.png')";
title.style.textAlign = 'center';
title.style.color = "#29FFFF";
title.style.fontFamily = "tahoma";
plybtn.style.height = "15px";
plybtn.style.position = 'fixed';
pbtn.style.height = "15px";
plybtn.style.left = "18px";
plybtn.style.top = '11px';
pbtn.style.top = "11px";
pbtn.style.left = "18px";
pbtn.style.position = 'fixed';
pbtn.src = "http://craft.yuribot.ml/Player/src/Images/paused.png";
plybtn.src = "http://craft.yuribot.ml/Player/src/Images/ply.png";
plybtn.onclick = function () {
    CallPause(plybtn, pbtn);
}
pbtn.onclick = function () {
    CallPlay(plybtn, pbtn);
}
title.innerHTML = "THIS IS THE TITLE SECTION";
title.style.fontSize = '8px';
player.appendChild(title);
player.appendChild(plybtn);
player.appendChild(pbtn);
document.body.appendChild(player);
```

I have no idea why this is happening. It was working before.

Comment: Why did you shorten play to ply?

Comment: This is working fine. You simply have cache issues with your browser.

Comment: it was 4am when I started this. So that's probably why

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me, I would try clearing your cache. In Chrome there is a setting to Disable cache while DevTools is open, you can set that through this link: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings